# Trouble when searching multiple data from mysql database in android

Tags: android, mysql, android-fragments, android-search

I am building an app in which I have a view with multiple tabs. Each tab contains a `RecyclerView` which gets populated from data in `MySQL`. So there is the `Activity` with the `ViewPager` and then each tab has its own `Fragment`. So I use the `Interface` to pass data from `Fragment` to `Activity` in order to be able to search for. The thing is that if I do not scroll over the tabs the recycler `List` is null so I cannot search. My question is would it be better if I search directly in the database or is there any other way to do this?

My App looks like this:

[image: App]

The code for passing data is:

**Interface:**

```
public interface CoffeeCommunicator {
    void sendCoffeeListData(String name, String image, String price);
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
        protected List<ProductList> doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                jsonResult = StringGenerator.inputStreamToString(in, getActivity());
                customList = new ArrayList<>();

                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult.toString());
                jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray(AppConstant.COFFEE_JSON_ARRAY);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                    jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                    price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
                    image = jsonChildNode.optString("image");
                    customList.add(new ProductList(image, name, price));
                    coffeeCommunicator.sendCoffeeListData(name, image, price);

                }
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return customList;
        }

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        coffeeCommunicator = (CoffeeCommunicator)activity;
    }
```

**Activity:**

```
@Override
    public void sendCoffeeListData(String name, String image, String price) {
        coffeesList.add(new ProductList(image, name, price));
    }
```

So then i have `coffeeList` available to search for.

Any ideas would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give code sample but you know your code better. Here's a sample:

In **Activity**:

```
populateList();

coffeeFragment = CoffeeFragment.newInstance();
coffeeFragment.setList(coffeesList);

void populateList() {
    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult.toString());
    jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray(AppConstant.COFFEE_JSON_ARRAY);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
        jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
        price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
        image = jsonChildNode.optString("image");
        coffeesList.add(new ProductList(image, name, price));
    }
}
```

**Fragment**:

```
public void setList(final List<ProductList> arrayList) {
{
    customList = arrayList;
}
```

**Note**:
Basically you fill data onto `coffeesList` in Activity. And then pass the List onto the Fragment. I pass a List object by calling a method `setList` in the Fragment because it is easier.

I hope that is clear enough. Is there a problem with this approach?

Comment: That basically is that i do all my asynctasks in the activity and then pass the data to the fragments right?

Comment: @helldawg13, Yes, that's right. This is one code design. The code example is one easy way. Have fun and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to query the database when doing an explicit search.  That will avoid the problem you're currently having of the data not yet being populated.

Comment: and how am i going to accomplish that?

Comment: Does your server API have a "search all categories" endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to populate data onto `RecyclerView`. In that case, your method is not the proper way. Here is one Android web page showing data population. Below is a code sample from that web page:

```
// specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Notes:

- In this code example, `myDataset` is simply an array of strings; this is the data. It can be any object actually. `MyAdapter` is a class that you create.
- RecyclerView uses the idea of **Adapter**, like in ListView.
- This method populates data immediately after the view is created. It uses virtual caching.

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: i have data in recyclerview...the problemm is that they are not available for search if i dont scroll the tabs so they can get populated

Comment: @helldawg13, In your case, one easy technique is to populate the List coffeesList even before the tab is in view. With your requirement, you cannot fill the data coffeesList in method doInBackground(). Do you need code sample for it for clarity?

Comment: I provide a sample code in another post because it has a different code design and approach.